# duration parameter not working with Folium plugin timestampedGeoJson

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I have the code ...

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson (
        {
                'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                'features': features
        },
        period = 'PT1M',
        transition_time = 100,
        loop = False,
        auto_play = False,
        duration = 'PT1M'
).add_to(m)

and I'm getting the error message ...
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duration'

The same happens with the parameter time_slider_drag_update. The map and time animation works fine without these parameters but I'm getting a stack of markers on top of each other because I'm not removing the markers after the timestamp has finished if that makes sense. I want the map to refresh not build.

Answer (score 0):

The `duration` parameter was added to the TimestampedGeoJson plugin in version 0.6.0. Double-check the version of folium you're using with `pip freeze | grep folium` and if it's < 0.6 then upgrade it with `pip install -U folium`.